# I am looking for a shorter way to create an extension method

Tags: rust

Is there a shorter way to write the following?
Do I need to declare a trait, and also implement it? Or can it be done in one? I can see why sometimes it is good to separate these two concepts. However, when used together (extension method pattern), is seems like un-necassary boiler plate.

```rust
pub trait StringToUtcDate {
    fn to_date(&self) -> DateTime<Utc>;
}

impl StringToUtcDate for String {
    fn to_date(&self) -> DateTime<Utc> {
       …
       result
    }
}

use chrono::{DateTime,Utc,NaiveDateTime,TimeZone};
```

Comment: You can have a default implementation, but only if that default is self-contained. What's so arduous about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but confuses my IDE. It does not know how the macro will re-write the code (or even that it will re-write it).

```rust
#[ext]
pub impl String {
    fn to_date(&self) -> DateTime<Utc> {
       …
       result
    }
}

use extend::ext;
```

`cargo.toml` must also include the `extend` crate.

Extract from `cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
…
extend = "1.1"
```

For more info see https://docs.rs/extend/latest/extend/